# Is there any common API/SDK to add custom tags to the existing AWS resources?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, sdk

I'm trying to implement an API that can add tags to all the existing resources in AWS. I can't use AWS CloudFormation approach for this.

Is there any common `API/SDK` approach to add custom tags to the existing AWS resources by passing the ***resourceIds***?

Answer (score 1):

What AWS resources do you mean. Do you mean an object in an Amazon S3 bucket? Many Service SDKs expose a Service client that lets you perform tagging operations. Consider the [S3Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html) service client, which is part of the **AWS SDK for Java V2**.

This service client has a method named **putObjectTagging** that lets you tag objects.  Likewise other service clients have similar                          tagging methods.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm trying to add tags to the Instances, VPCs, Subnets, SecurityGroups and RouteTables. Does all these are possible through SDKs?

Comment: Many do - such as the Ec2Client service client https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html. Look at each Javadoc for the Service client you are interested in.

Comment: For Java - see the various Service Clients for various AWS Services here -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any common API/SDK to add tags to different AWS resources. But Here is what I got it and used for my requirement.

Search for `Resource Groups & Tag Editor` in the `AWS Console` and go to `Tag Editor` section, you can see an UI to select resource types and option to add new tags for a region. You can select multiple resources based on the region and resource type you choose and **`apply the set of tags together in a single shot`**.